# extjs grid disappears on column resize

Tags: extjs4

I have an ext.js grid that when the user is resizing the columns, occassionally all the columns will all disappear. I tried setting the width of the grid and did not seem to make a difference. Here is the code:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'ViolList_grid',
        title: config.title,
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('BailCardStore'),
        selModel: sm,
        maxHeight: 390,
        columns: [
            { header: 'Violation', dataIndex: 'lawCd' },
            { header: 'Description', dataIndex: 'lawCdDesc', flex: 1, sortable: false,
    renderer: formatLineWrap },
            { header: 'Amount Due', dataIndex: 'beforeAmt', renderer: 
       Ext.util.Format.usMoney }
        ],
        frame: true,
        autoscroll: false,
        renderTo: Ext.get(config.renderTo)

    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a newbie to ext.js.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have the issue after reconfiguring the grid. Are you reconfiguring the grid too?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding enableDragDrop : true to Ext.grid.Panel.